# R error when using a dataframe with named samples - 'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one

Tags: r

I have a database of famous people's voices and I'm currently trying to build a model which predicts whether a voice sounds male or female using the `randomForest` function. This works fine when I delete the celebrity's name from the dataframe before building the model, however I want to be able to find out which voices the model gets wrong, so I've tried creating the same model without deleting the voice name first. This is the code:

```
library(randomForest)

# Build a random forest model
rf_model <- randomForest(Gender ~ -VoiceName, data = dataset)

# Compute the accuracy of the random forest on a validation set
validation$pred <- predict(rf_model, validation)
mean(validation$pred == validation$Gender)
```

However, when I run this, I see the following error:

```
Error in reformulate(attributes(Terms)$term.labels) : 

'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
```

This makes no sense to me, because each of these voice samples have a VoiceName which returns TRUE when I run `is.character(dataset$VoiceName)`. Does anybody have any tips on what's going wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a "dot" between `~` and `-VoiceName`. This means

```
rf_model <- randomForest(Gender ~. -VoiceName, data = dataset)
```